# Assign values to X arrays in a smart way

Tags: c#, arrays

I have three arrays:

```
int[] player1 = new int[22];
int[] player2 = new int[22];
int[] player3 = new int[22];
```

And I have a declared a int player and a random:

```
int players = 0;
Random rand = new Random();
players = rand.Next(1, 4);
```

I have a for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int p = 1; p < players + 1; p++) {
    }
}
```

Inside that for I have another for.

Dependent on what random players has been selected I want to assign values to my arrays. So for example if players is 3, in my second array I want to assign values to:

```
int[] player1 = new int[22];
int[] player2 = new int[22];
int[] player3 = new int[22];
```

To my question:
Is there a good way to type, first round assign to player1, second round to player2 and third round assign to player3.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int p = 1; p < players + 1; p++) {
            // assign to arrays. ? = if there is a good way to first assign to player1, then      player2 then player3
            ? = ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Store them in an array/list as well, not in a separate variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make an [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) of players?

```
int[][] players = new[] { new int[22], new int[22], new int[22] };
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int p = 0; p < players.Length; p++) {
        players[p][i] = rand.Next(1, 4);
    }
}
```

Or for that matter, a [2-dimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx):

```
int[,] players = new int[22, 3];                      // or [3, 22]
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int p = 0; p < players.GetLength(1); p++) {  // or GetLength(0)
        players[i, p] = rand.Next(1, 4);              // or [p, i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the jagged array.